# Is this Shirk(Urgent answer pls)

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, salat, practical-islam

My mom is a computer teacher and she got board in the corridor to decorate and she added an animated drawing to make it look good.I told her not to hang it but she says who cares about angels not entering there. I said that it is shirk too but she did not listen. She teaches children maybe 3rd to 4th grade . Is it permissible for children though it is hanged?She says it is normal for everyone and not to be extreme.what about worksheets she prepares for children which have images. I heard that it is permissible for children.

Answer (score 0):

The majority opinion in Sunni fiqh is that drawing and hanging up cartoons is a haram, hence a sin. According to Shia fiqh it is permitted (halal).

Only if it depicts deities or objects of worship, it is shirk in all fiqh.